# Putty Login error through SSH (Network error: Connection timeout)

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I am trying to login into one(X) server using putty (port 22), and it is showing Fatal Error in a pop-up with the message `Network error: Connection timed out`.

But when I am in different server(Y) on command prompt using

```
ssh (X)hostname
```

it is working. It seems only an issue with putty.

I am able to ping X server from Y server.

At the same time, I am able to log into some different servers(Y,Z) through putty.

Comment: This could be any of a number of problems, e.g. routing, firewalling, wrong IP, etc.; without detailed info nothing can be said about the cause.

Comment: "Connection timed out" suggests that the machine on which you're running putty can't reach X.  I'm guessing if you tried to ping X you would see that ping would fail too.

Comment: Server X is pinging .

Comment: What is the result of telnet x 22. X would be your server ip and 22 would be the port on which SSH server is running.

Comment: X server is connecting/pinging from every where except from putty.

Comment: does connecting include telnet?

Comment: No Telnet connection was establishing

Comment: Then in that case you need to check windows firewall or if both the machines are in different network then the firewall between them is blocking your connection. First suspect is windows firewall.

Comment: Hello Praveen, is it working now?

Comment: No Vidyadhar. :(